# How to write bash script to re-attach to a existing linux screen?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to write a bash script to re-attach to the existing linux screen, perform some commands and then detach from that screen. I know to create a new linux screen in detached mode and perform some commands. But I haven't found a way to re-attach to a existing linux screen.

Comment: Doesn't `screen -r` help?

Comment: @Roman no, I tried that also, it's not working

Comment: If this is for a script, you can't just attach to the screen, then continue with the rest of you script. The attach command doesn't actually exit *until* you detach.

Answer (score 2):

You can give a name to a screen session by using the -S option.
Example : `screen -dS NAME <command>`

Then you can reattach to that session using `screen -r NAME`

Answer (score 1):

try this;

```
user@host:/screen -ls 

There are screens on:
        29229558.pts-5.host   (Detached)
        46661728.pts-22.host   (Detached)

user@host:/screen -r 46661728.pts-22.host
```

If you see (attached) as below;

```
user@host:/screen -ls
There are screens on:
        29229558.pts-5.host   (Detached)
        46661728.pts-22.host   (Atached)

screen -D -r 46661728.pts-22.host
```

Answer (score 0):

To re-attach to the screen you have to follow this steps:

Before de-attaching from the screen, execute:

```
STDOUTTERM=$(who -m|awk '{print $2}')
```

Then you can attach stdout to whatever you want. When you finish, to reattach to stdout, execute this:

```
exec > /dev/$STDOUTTERM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a command to a running screen using `screen -X exec`.  See the man page for redirection options.

```
screen -X exec ls
```

Alternatively you can send text to a running screen's stdin buffer using `screen -X paste`, as if the user had typed it.  This can be a way of running commands inside an interactive shell.

```
screen -X register a "ls\n"
screen -X paste a
```